# Convert alphanumeric string to given values for each, then add them for a total number

Tags: vbscript, sum

I'm having a difficult time wording exactly what I'm doing, but basically I have variable length alphanumeric data being fed to a program, and I want to find out the total "pixel width" of the string, based on a fixed list of A = 3 pxl, B = 3 pxl, I = 1 pxl, etc...

I would list all of the pixel values of each letter and number, and then would like the script to take the input: ex. "THIS IS THE STRING", and convert it to the numbers I've assigned add them up and total them giving me the total sum as an output (I would also assign a number for a space " " and punctuation).

So: "THIS IS A STRING" would be "3+3+1+3+2+1+3+2+3+3+3+2+3+3+3+1+3+3 = 45"

Answer (score 1):

You need a table/array of pixel widthes indexed by ASCII codes. Then you can loop over the string's characters and sum the widthes. Like:

```
>> Dim a(255)
>> a(65) = 3
>> a(66) = 3
>> a(Asc("I")) = 1
>> s = "AIB"
>> n = 0
>> For p = 1 To Len(s)
>>     n = n + a(Asc(Mid(s, p, 1)))
>> Next
>> WScript.Echo n
>>
7
```

Comment: I'd suggest a dictionary. But even then it isn't as simple as adding the individual widths when [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) comes into play (not to mention ligatures).

Comment: Thank you, Ansgar. The Font/Kerning etc, will be fixed, and the result doesn't need to be DEAD accurate to the pixel. I only have to do it this way because the program I'm using cannot figure out a fields length by the text input to it, but i need to know the length for some variable animation movements...

So what you suggest is I create a dictionary like:

<%
Dim d
Set d=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "A","3"
d.Add "B","3"
d.Add "C","3"
d.Add "D","3"
Response.Write("The value of key gr is: " & d.Item("gr"))
%>

Comment: @Mloucks Not exactly. You still need to parse the string and add the values as Ekkehard.Horner lined out in the answer (`For p = 1 To Len(s) : n = n + d(Mid(s, p, 1)) : Next`). The dictionary just provides a more elegant way of mapping characters to their individual width.

Comment: The software that will be reading the output value can actually do the sum for me, so I think I'd want to assign values like d.Add "A","3+", for all letters/numbers/special characters (is that possible), and then have logic to check for the last character of the string to remove the "+", then have the software sum the equation for me... I'd assume that would simplify the script a lot, no?

Comment: @Mloucks No, it won't.